# ASP.NET MVC: redirect users to their areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have three roles in my ASP.Net mvc application: Admin,Client,ProjectManager.
I have a login page in my default application Area, and then I redirect users per their role to their defined area:

```
bool isAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id,ApplicationUser.Role_SiteAdmin);
bool isProjectManager = UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id,ApplicationUser.Role_ProjectManageer);
await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
if (isProjectManager==true)
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new { area = "Admin" });
else
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

In above example, `ProjectManager` is directed to `Admin` area and `Admin` role is routed to Default application Area.

I want to know are there any global method, which I can redirect user to their specified `Area` if they visit other areas? E.g. if ProjectManager moved to Client Area, it automatically redirect him to his own Area?

Comment: I think it can be done using a custom attribute that redirects the action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438998/asp-net-mvc-redirect-from-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) . It allows you to give access to the action based on the user roles. eg [Authorize(Roles="SiteAdmin")]